# Angularjs $routeProvider and $http not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started working on AngularJS recently and now I am stuck and I can't seem to find the solution. I think I am not understanding the basics of $routeProvider and $http. Here is my code and any help will be appreciated.

My  app.js

```
var bullTank = angular.module('bullTank',[
    'ngRoute',
    'btController'
]);

bullTank.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/getUsers',{
            templateUrl: 'getUsers.html',
            controller : 'btListController'
        }).
        otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/getUsers'
            });
    }
]);
```

controller.js

```
var btController = angular.module('btController',[]);

btController.controller('btListController', ['$scope','$http',  function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('../webservices/getUsers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data;
    })
}]);
```

And my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="bullTank">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bulltank admin</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header class="navbar navbar-bright navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">BullTank</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h1><img src="img/bulltank.png" id="logo">
                    <!--<p class="lead">The easiest way to apply Bootstrap</p>-->
                </h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /cont -->
</div>

<!-- Begin Body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">

            <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#/getUsers">Manage App Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sec1">Add/Remove Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sec2">Manage Banner Advertisement Manager</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sec3">Content Management</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

getUsers.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!--Sidebar content-->


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <!--Body content-->


            <table class="table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Profilepic</th>
                    <th>Cover Video</th>
                    <th>Private</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `getUsers.html`?

Comment: There you go, added!

Comment: what is the actual question / problem?

Comment: Nothing is loading in n-view. It is redirecting to 'getUsers' but nothing happens

Comment: Check this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BAzbfqh99YjAT48f0c5E?p=preview. At least routes are working. $http get replaced with an alert. otherwise route config changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine.

First, go to `/getUsers` from your browser, check the HTML source and see if `getUsers.html` is loaded into `ng-view`. If it is, then `$routeProvider` works.

Secondly, change your `$http` request as follows:

```
$http.get('../webservices/getUsers.php').success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data;
});
```

Then open browser Console, go to `/getUsers`, check the console and see what is logged there. It must be an array of users, otherwise it won't work.

If nothing is logged, then switch to a Network tab where you can see all AJAX requests made so far. See if `../webservices/getUsers.php` is there, and it returns status code 200. You can also check the request and the response headers, types etc.

Note: this whole guideline assumes you have no errors in browser console (I know one problem in your code, but you need to learn how to debug your code so I'll let you find it yourself.)